# session_set_cookie_params specifying a path not working? can read sesh vars from differennt folder

Tags: php, session

I've had a look through the related queries and nothing is working.

I have a https domain and when logging I create several session vars. The login script would be at https://www.domain.com/dir1/login.php

I have an application in another folder or dir on this domain and I do not want the session to carry from one dir to the other.

I have been trying to set the path with session_set_cookie_params at the top of my login script before `session_start()` but I am still able to access the session vars from the second dir.

eg.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/dir1");
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/dir1/");
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/abs/path/dir1");
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/abs/path/dir1/");
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/dir1", ".domain.com/dir1", true); //tried using true here as the domain is https
```

None of these seem to be effective as if I browse to https://www.domain.com/dir2/page.php all of the session vars set in dir1 are accessible which I am trying to prevent.

I realise I can set a session var when logginng into dir1

```
$_SESSION["logged_into"]="dir1";
```

and then kick them out if they try to browse into dir 2

```
if ($_SESSION["logged_into"]!="dir2") {
    header("Location:$secureurl/logout.php");
}
```

but I really want to hide the whole session from dir2.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Did you check if the changing params actually changed the cookie? Does the /path stuff show up in the cookie in your browser? Using Firebug's cookie inspector to check.

Comment: Thank for the tip. I thought I got it working yesterday by removing the leading / off a dir name but maybe there were caching issues or something because this morning I need the / in order to make it work. Thanks.